# Vue native is always executing App.js instead of .vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-native

I made the first process of installation of vue-native, and I'm following the "Getting Started" Hello world tutorial (https://vue-native.io/getting-started.html), but the `App.vue` is never executed, only the `App.js`. If I remove the `App.js` I get an error:

> "Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js""

How can I fix this problem to make it work and follow the tutorial with any problem?

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <text class="text-color-primary">My Vue Native App</text>
    </view>
</template>

<style>
.container {
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.text-color-primary {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Thank you

Comment: it would help if you post more info such as folder structure and your export statement on your app.js.  from the error it is looking for a js file named AppEntry.js? so post your folder structure and a bit of information about how you installed vue and or created the app - like did you use vue-cli?

Comment: I have edited the question, I have added the App.js, App.vue and folder structure.

Comment: Sorry, am a bit confused here. Are you using `vue` or `react`? How did you wireup vue?  did you use the vue-cli to create the app, I mean that is your get-started doc and upon following it, it works just fine

Comment: I'm using Vue, I just typed in the console "vue-native init <project-name>", and then I executed it with "npm start"

Answer (score 6):

Although the answers might work for some. There is another way to fix this issue without deleting any files.
Navigate to the node modules folder.
Search for the expo folder.

Open the **AppEntry.js** file.
It should look like this:

```
import 'expo/build/Expo.fx';
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
import { activateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';

import App from '../../App'; // we will change this!

if (__DEV__) {
  activateKeepAwake();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Modify **Appentry.js** to this:

```
import 'expo/build/Expo.fx';
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
import { activateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';

import App from '../../App.vue'; // Will use App.vue as the entry point

if (__DEV__) {
  activateKeepAwake();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
At first you delete `app.js` This will give you an error, but don't worry. You will have to run the `npm install` command. After this, run vue-native again with `npm start`

This will run the app.vue file normally

Comment: I have the same issue, and this solution don't worked

Comment: Not working! The error is still ` Unable to resolve module `./App` from `/home/abc/coding/learn/vue-native/sample/index.js`: The module `./App` could not be found from `/home/abc/coding/learn/vue-native/sample/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:`

Answer (score 0):

Had a same issue.  Below works for me

In app.json add

`"sourceExts": [ "js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "jsx", "vue"]`

Inside "packagerOpts"

`"packagerOpts": 
{ "sourceExts": [ "js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "jsx", "vue"],
 "config": "metro.config.js"}`

Read it from:  https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing on web browser(which isn't production ready), i think it will look for App entry file in this order js > json > vue. So i think it's impossible it will seek out App.vue.

For viewing on android phone, stop the Expo Dev Tools in terminal, delete App.js, then run `npm start order` or `npm run android`